# can any one tell me how to write long equation in multline i tried with coding below but some errors of \right and \left appear

Tags: errors, multline

```
\begin{multline*}
\displaystyle \left \| f  \right \|_{M\dot{K}^{\alpha(\cdot),q}_{p(\cdot),
\lambda}(\mathbb{R}^{n})} \approx \max \left\{ \sup_{L\leqslant0,L\in 
\mathbb{Z}}2^{-L\lambda}\left ( \sum_{k=-\infty}^{L}2^{k\alpha(0)q}\left \| 
f\chi_{k} \right \|^{q}_{L^{p(\cdot)}} \right )^{1/q},\\\sup_{L>0,L\in
\mathbb{Z}}\left[ 2^{-L\lambda}\left ( \sum_{k=-\infty}^{-1}2^{k\alpha(0)q}
\left \| f\chi_{k} \right \|^{q}_{L^{p(\cdot)}} \right )^{1/q}\\
+2^{-L\lambda}\left ( \sum_{k=0}^{L}2^{k\alpha(\infty)q}\left \|
 f\chi_{k} \right \|^{q}_{L^{p(\cdot)}} \right )^{1/q}\right] \right\}
 \end{multline*}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Can you update your question with a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: you should not use `\displaystyle` (display math is already displaystyle and you can not use left-right spanning lines. (there are several answers about that already so this question is probably a duplicate, use `\bigl` and `\bigr` instead of `\left` and `\right`

Answer (score 2):

The main problem with your code is that you try to attempt to use `\left\{...\right\}` and `\left[...\right` across line breaks. This doesn't work -- and it never has worked. I suggest you use explicitly sized curly braces and square brackets instead: `\biggl\{...\biggr\}` and `\biggl[...\biggr]`.

Another problem is that the round parentheses that surround the summation terms are too large, typographically speaking. Replace all three instances of `\left(...\right)` with `\biggl(...\biggr)`.

Third, the use of `multline*` seems suboptimal as there are actually some fairly obvious alignment points candidates across the lines. Use an `align*` environment instead.

Fourth, instead of writing `\left \| f  \right \|`, define and use `\norm` macro, as is done below. It'll do wonders for the legibility of your code.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\norm{f}_{M\dot{K}^{\alpha(\cdot),q}_{p(\cdot),\lambda} (\mathbb{R}^n)} \approx \max 
\biggl\{ 
&\sup_{\smash[b]{\substack{L\leqslant0,\\ L\in\mathbb{Z}}}} 
2^{-L\lambda} \biggl(\,\smashoperator[r]{\sum_{k=-\infty}^{L}}
2^{k\alpha(0)q}\,\norm{f\chi_{k}}^{q}_{L^{p(\cdot)}} \biggr)^{\!\!1/q},\\
&\sup_{\smash[b]{\substack{L>0,\\ L\in\mathbb{Z}}}} 
\biggl[ 
2^{-L\lambda} \biggl(\,\smashoperator[r]{\sum_{k=-\infty}^{-1}}
2^{k\alpha(0)q}\,\norm{f\chi_{k}}^{q}_{L^{p(\cdot)}} \biggr)^{\!\!1/q}\\
&\qquad +
2^{-L\lambda} \biggl(\sum_{k=0}^{L}
2^{k\alpha(\infty)q}\,\norm{f\chi_{k}}^{q}_{L^{p(\cdot)}} \biggr)^{\!\!1/q}\,
\biggr] 
\biggr\}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks a lot dear

Answer (score 1):

I propose this layout: use a larger text width (loading `geometry`), write the l.h.s. on a separate line at the left margin (with the `fleqn` from `nccmath`, to be loaded *before* `mathtools`)), and  have the r.h.s. slightly moved right on two lines with an alignment. Also, I chase the delimiters sizes manually, and defined a `\norm` command with `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` from `mathtools` in order to simplify abit the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}\Vert\Vert

\begin{document}

\begin{fleqn}
\begin{align*}
& \norm[\big]{f}_{M\dot{K}^{\alpha(\cdot),q}_{p(\cdot),\lambda}(\mathbb{R}^{n})} \approx \\
 \MoveEqLeft[-2.5]
\begin{aligned}
\max\Biggl\{ & \sup_{L\leqslant0,L\in \mathbb{Z}}2^{-L\lambda}\biggl( \sum_{k=-\infty}^{L}2^{k\alpha(0)q}\norm[\big]{f\chi_{k}}^{q}_{L^{p(\cdot)}} \biggr)^{\mkern-6mu 1/q}\mkern-9mu ,\\%
  & \sup_{L>0,L\in \mathbb{Z}}\Biggl[ 2^{-L\lambda}\biggl( \sum_{k=-\infty}^{-1}2^{k\alpha(0)q}\norm[\big]{f\chi_{k}}^{q}_{L^{p(\cdot)}} \biggr)^{\!\!1/q}
   + 2^{-L\lambda}\biggl( \sum_{k=0}^{L}2^{k\alpha(\infty)q}\norm{f\chi_{k}}^{q}_{L^{p(\cdot)}}\biggr)^{\!\!1/q}\Biggr]\Biggr\}
    \end{aligned}
\end{align*}
\end{fleqn}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\begin{multline*}
\left \| f \right \|_{ M\dot{K}^{\alpha(\cdot),q}_{p(\cdot), \lambda} (\mathbb{R}^{n}) }
\approx \max
\{
 \sup_{L\leqslant0,L\in \mathbb{Z}}
 2^{-L\lambda}
 \left( \sum_{k=-\infty}^{L} 2^{k\alpha(0)q} \left \| f\chi_{k} \right \|^{q}_{L^{p(\cdot)}} \right )^{1/q},
\\
\sup_{L>0,L\in \mathbb{Z}}
[
 2^{-L\lambda}
 \left(
  \sum_{k=-\infty}^{-1} 2^{k\alpha(0)q}
   \left \| f\chi_{k} \right \|^{q}_{L^{p(\cdot)}}
  \right )^{1/q}
 \\
 +2^{-L\lambda}
 \left( \sum_{k=0}^{L} 2^{k \alpha (\infty) q}
        \left \| f\chi_{k} \right \|^{q}_{L^{p(\cdot)}} \right )^{1/q}
]
\}
\end{multline*}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your proposed solution currenlty doesn't scale the pairs of curly braces and square brackets. Can you think of a way to change their sizes?