# Error of Undefined control sequence. \end{frame} appears

Tags: errors, mdframed

I am using coding below for slides, but an error of Undefined control sequence. `\end{frame}` appears and also `\smashoperator[r]` not works properly in slides, Need kind suggestions for this issue.

```
\begin{frame}
    \begin{propa}\label{proposition1}
        Let $p(\cdot)\in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^{n}), q\in(0,\infty]$ and $\lambda\in(0,\infty]$. If $\alpha(\cdot)\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})\cap \mathcal{P}^{log}_{0}(\mathbb{R}^{n})\cap \mathcal{P}^{log}_{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$. then
        \begin{align*}
        \norm{f}_{M\dot{K}^{\alpha(\cdot),q(\cdot)}_{p(\cdot),\lambda} (\mathbb{R}^n)} \approx \max 
        \biggl\{ 
        &\sup_{\smash[b]{\substack{L\leqslant0,\\ L\in\mathbb{Z}}}} 
        2^{-L\lambda} \biggl(\,\smashoperator[r]{\sum_{k=-\infty}^{L}}
        \,\norm{2^{k\alpha(0)}f\chi_{k}}^{q(0)}_{L^{p(\cdot)}} \biggr)^{\!\!1/q(0)},\\
        &\sup_{\smash[b]{\substack{L>0,\\ L\in\mathbb{Z}}}} 
        \biggl[ 
        2^{-L\lambda} \biggl(\,\smashoperator[r]{\sum_{k=-\infty}^{-1}}
        \,\norm{2^{k\alpha(0)}f\chi_{k}}^{q(0)}_{L^{p(\cdot)}} \biggr)^{\!\!1/q(0)}\\
        &\qquad +
        2^{-L\lambda} \biggl(\sum_{k=0}^{L}
        \,\norm{2^{k\alpha(\infty)}f\chi_{k}}^{q(\infty)}_{L^{p(\cdot)}} \biggr)^{\!\!1/q(\infty)}\,
        \biggr] 
        \biggr\}.
        \end{align*}
    \end{propa}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Please, give a fully compilable code.

Comment: using \newtheorem{propa}{Proposition} as a proposition envieroment.

Comment: We can’t test our guesses unless you give us [a MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can any one tell me how to write long equation in multline i tried with coding below but some errors of \right and \left appear](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/539257/can-any-one-tell-me-how-to-write-long-equation-in-multline-i-tried-with-coding-b). In that posting, I provided [an answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/539277/5001) which you appear to have copied *verbatim* into the code shown above, *except* that you failed to copy the preamble instructions `\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}` and `\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}`.

Comment: When i used above code for thesis format it works as a proposition but when i used this proposition in presentation slide and use \frame environment the error mention above is appeared

Comment: @ShoaibAssar - The earlier code definitely won't work if you don't execute `\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}` and `\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}` in the preamble.